# PyCharm highlights HTML incorrectly

Tags: html, pycharm

I've somehow managed to mess up some setting in my PyCharm. As you can see from the attached screenshot, it highlights HTML incorrectly. I'm not entirely sure, but it seems to highlight everything that is surrounding div elements.
Any idea where this is configured and how to reset it back to default?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this problem exactly, but you could try...

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts

Click the gear to the right of 'Scheme' -> Restore defaults... -> OK

Note this will likely revert all of your color scheme settings, so it might be good to save off your current settings before you try this. There are some HTML specific highlighting at

File -> Settings -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> HTML

However, I don't see anything related specifically to div tags.

Comment: The scheme is already on defaults as the 'Restore defaults' option is greyed out even on the highest level. I'm waiting on feedback from PyCharm developers, but thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Support solved it by disabling div injection.

[screenshot](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/_persistent/injection.png?file=74-422042&c=true)